# How to enumerate navigation stack in metro

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to build breadcrumb menu in my metro app (XAML/C# approach) and in order to do it I need to enumerate thru navigation stack. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this. Does anyone can give some example how I can see what pages are on the navigation stack ?

What I found is a method Frame.GetNavigationState() but this is just a serialized state and I would prefer not to dig with that and rather use something with is strongly typed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know your specific scenario, but in general, breadcrumb UI is generally frowned upon from a UX perspective.  Just FYI...

Comment: @JeffBrand-MSFT - frowned upon from a UX perspective? That's insane. It can be the absolute quickest way to jump _directly_ to a page you were on (a few pages ago). The only reason it should be frowned upon is if you _rely_ on it as your only or main navigation system.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this task by maintaining your own navigation stack somewhere (overriding OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom on each page, and writing you your own navigation state collection).